# Writing to excel and dates

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datetime

I have written a C# application that reads DataTables from a database (SQL Server) and exports them to Excel files. Unfortunately, in this database, the columns representing dates are sometimes represented as VARCHAR (as opposed to DATETIME).

When the column data type is DATETIME, the Excel file is generated with the value in my desired format, which is dd/mm/yyyy. On the other hand, when the data type is VARCHAR, the result is mm/dd/yyyy. I need to fix this.

The problem is that I do now know a priory if a VARCHAR column represents a date, so I should (I believe) instruct the application to export VARCHAR literally, without doing any conversion (the verbatim value on the database is correct).

How can I do this? If necessary, I can post the code that writes the Excel starting from the DataTable.

Thanks!

Giuseppe

Comment: *If necessary, I can post the code that writes the Excel starting from the DataTable* Yes I think it is necessary :)

Comment: My suggestion would be to change select query in SQL to select something like `SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2013-09-13 16:01:00', 120)`. Use Column name istead of hardcoded date.

Comment: unfortunately, the SQL selects must be SELECT * as I cannot know column names in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick that works. Adding a blank space in front of the cell value, the conversion is not performed in case of varchar:

mysheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = " " + drow[i - 1].ToString();